# View all of the built in functions that take in a particular data type in Python

Tags: python, function, object

How would I be able to view all of built in functions take in a particular object(`list, str, int, float` ....) as its parameter for example some functions that pass `list` are `max(), min(), len() ....`. I can view all of the methods by simply `dir(object)` like `dir(list)`. How would I be able to do it for functions?

Comment: Python is not statically typed. Functions don't generally define the types they accept.

Comment: @Chris: It's *possible* some magic with the `.pyi` files providing type hinting for built-ins might let you build tooling to do this sort of thing, through the rather ugly process of basically just asking, over and over, "are the type hints on any of this function's arguments compatible with `<provided type>`?" but I'm not aware of any existing tools for doing it. But yeah, generally, the answer is "read the docs".

Comment: max(), mint(), len() all accept **iterables**, (objects that at least define `__iter__`) not `list` types. So, using that as an example, there is no function that should scan your entire codebase for objects that define that function...

Comment: Python uses duck typing, so any object that supports the functions called by the function will work.  Doesn't matter what the type is.